# How to show news feed from remote mysql database in offline android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a web application where users can share messages,images,videos like Facebook.  I developed an android application for this using java. I am using PHP (webservice) to retrieve data from mysql database. It works fine if the mobile is having internet connection. If the mobile is not having internet connection I am displaying an error message for now. But I want to show my users the messages that are already retrieved when the mobile is in offline mode as how Facebook shows old news feed in offline. I read that we need to store the data in internal sqllite database.If so, how how can I achieve this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this by using the embedded SQLite, which is the embedded database in android. You could read the data from php, write it on the SQLite and then read offline from it. For more information, I found a very easy tutorial for you at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to sync the remote mysql with with internal SQLite. How can I achieve this in easy way?

Answer (score 0):

hopes this helps you getting started..

You need to create a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper in which we declare fields, tables and database methods..etc like so

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


//Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";


//Tables

private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";


//Columns

//Table User
private static final String KEY_USERS_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_USERS_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String KEY_USERS_PASSWORD = "password";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //CREATE TABLE USERS
    String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "(" +
    KEY_USERS_ID +  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    KEY_USERS_USERNAME + " TEXT, " +
    KEY_USERS_PASSWORD +  " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);


    onCreate(db);


}

public void addUser(String username, String password)
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {

        db.beginTransaction();


            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_USERS_USERNAME, username);
            values.put(KEY_USERS_PASSWORD, password);

            db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);



          db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {}
    finally
    {
      db.endTransaction();
    }


    db.close();


}
```

}

As you can see in this example we are creating our database, created a table called USERS which has an autoincremented int id and 2 other columns for username and password...then I included a method to add a new user to the table